# getting : undefined is not a function on getting collection from web-api

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have a *web api* which returns `IHttpActionResult(myCollection)` on Get.

My angular *JS* controller is has a function :

```
   $scope.loadcollection = function($defer, params) {
    console.log("inside loadcollection ");
    mySvc.getCollection().then(function(myCollection) {
      //$defer.resolve(myCollection);
        $scope.recievedCollection= myCollection
        console.log("invoices are : ", $scope.recievedCollection);
    });
```

My service in angular *JS* is as follows :

```
app.factory('mySvc', ['$resource', '$q', 'serviceHelperSvc',
    function($resource, $q, serviceHelper) {
    var myObject= serviceHelper.collectionObj;

        var getCollection= function() {

          /*  var d = $q.defer();
            var resp = Invoice.query();
            console.log("resp is : ", resp);
            d.resolve(true);

            return d.promise;*/
            return myObject.query();
        };
}]);
```

my serviceHelperSvc is as follows:

```
app.factory('serviceHelperSvc', ['$http', '$resource',
function($http, $resource) {
    var config = {
        "apiurl": "http://localhost:8000/"
    }

    var baseUrl = config.apiurl;
    var buildUrl = function(resourceUrl) {
        return baseUrl + resourceUrl;
    };

    var addRequestHeader = function(key, value) {

    };
    return {
        AuthorizationToken: $resource(buildUrl("Token"), null, {
            requestToken: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                }
            }
        }),
        collectionObj: $resource(buildUrl('api/CollectionObj/:CollectionObjId'), {
            CollectionObjId: '@Id'
        }, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        })
    };
}
]);
```

when i try to run this, i get undefined is not a function at `mySvc.getCollection().then(function(myCollection)`

before `then(function(myCollection)`.

when i try using the defer promise approach, i get an exception at the same place saying `$promise is not defined`

Comment: Please add the angular version.

Comment: angular version as in ?

Comment: As in v1.0.8 or 1.2.20 or 1.3.0-beta6

Comment: I'm having a near identical issue. Looking forward to some help on this!

Comment: angular version is 1.2.0